# how can i use drop box to check for a new version of my app

Tags: java, android

Hi guys ive just implemented the open source project Auto Update apk.. Because my app is not on play store and it was getting very silly waiting for people to download new updates.. ive had no problems getting it to work it was pretty straight forward to implement.. My problem is the amount of data allowance they give u on a free account... ive used all my quote for the month in less than aweek.. what want to know is how i can change the code so it checks aweb address of my choosing instead of theres.. ive read that it would involve a .txt file that my app would read with new version number inside..

any ideas of what to change in the auto update apk class to achive this? also what would the txt file need to contain. thanks guys n girls

this is the main code for the auto updateapk project

```
 public class AutoUpdateApk extends Observable {

// this class is supposed to be instantiated in any of your activities or,
// better yet, in Application subclass. Something along the lines of:
//
//  private AutoUpdateApk aua;  <-- you need to add this line of code
//
//  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      setContentView(R.layout.main);
//
//      aua = new AutoUpdateApk(getApplicationContext());   <-- and add this line too
//
public AutoUpdateApk(Context ctx) {
    setupVariables(ctx);
}

// set icon for notification popup (default = application icon)
//
public static void setIcon( int icon ) {
    appIcon = icon;
}

// set name to display in notification popup (default = application label)
//
public static void setName( String name ) {
    appName = name;
}

// set update interval (in milliseconds)
//
// there are nice constants in this file: MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS
// you may use them to specify update interval like: 5 * DAYS
//
// please, don't specify update interval below 1 hour, this might
// be considered annoying behaviour and result in service suspension
//
public void setUpdateInterval(long interval) {
    if( interval > 60 * MINUTES ) {
        UPDATE_INTERVAL = interval;
    } else {
        Log_e(TAG, "update interval is too short (less than 1 hour)");
    }
}

// software updates will use WiFi/Ethernet only (default mode)
//
public static void disableMobileUpdates() {
    mobile_updates = false;
}

// software updates will use any internet connection, including mobile
// might be a good idea to have 'unlimited' plan on your 3.75G connection
//
public static void enableMobileUpdates() {
    mobile_updates = true;
}

// call this if you want to perform update on demand
// (checking for updates more often than once an hour is not recommended
// and polling server every few minutes might be a reason for suspension)
//
public void checkUpdatesManually() {
    checkUpdates(true);     // force update check
}

public static final String AUTOUPDATE_CHECKING = "autoupdate_checking";
public static final String AUTOUPDATE_NO_UPDATE = "autoupdate_no_update";
public static final String AUTOUPDATE_GOT_UPDATE = "autoupdate_got_update";
public static final String AUTOUPDATE_HAVE_UPDATE = "autoupdate_have_update";

public void clearSchedule() {
    schedule.clear();
}

public void addSchedule(int start, int end) {
    schedule.add(new ScheduleEntry(start,end));
}
//
// ---------- everything below this line is private and does not belong to the public API ----------
 //
protected final static String TAG = "AutoUpdateApk";

private final static String ANDROID_PACKAGE = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
//  private final static String API_URL = "http://auto-update-apk.appspot.com/check";
private final static String API_URL = "http://www.auto-update-apk.com/check";
 protected static Context context = null;
protected static SharedPreferences preferences;
private final static String LAST_UPDATE_KEY = "last_update";
private static long last_update = 0;

private static int appIcon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
private static int versionCode = 0;     // as low as it gets
private static String packageName;
private static String appName;
private static int device_id;

public static final long MINUTES = 60 * 1000;
public static final long HOURS = 60 * MINUTES;
public static final long DAYS = 24 * HOURS;

// 3-4 hours in dev.mode, 1-2 days for stable releases
private static long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 48 * DAYS;    // how often to check

private static boolean mobile_updates = false;      // download updates over wifi only

private final static Handler updateHandler = new Handler();
protected final static String UPDATE_FILE = "update_file";
protected final static String SILENT_FAILED = "silent_failed";
private final static String MD5_TIME = "md5_time";
private final static String MD5_KEY = "md5";

private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0xBEEF;
private static long WAKEUP_INTERVAL = 15 * MINUTES;

private class ScheduleEntry {
    public int start;
    public int end;

    public ScheduleEntry(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
   private static ArrayList<ScheduleEntry> schedule = new   

 ArrayList<ScheduleEntry>();

private Runnable periodicUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        checkUpdates(false);
        updateHandler.removeCallbacks(periodicUpdate);  // remove whatever others may have posted
        updateHandler.postDelayed(this, WAKEUP_INTERVAL);
    }
};

private BroadcastReceiver connectivity_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        // do application-specific task(s) based on the current network state, such
        // as enabling queuing of HTTP requests when currentNetworkInfo is connected etc.
        boolean not_mobile = currentNetworkInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE") ? false : true;
        if( currentNetworkInfo.isConnected() && (mobile_updates || not_mobile) ) {
            checkUpdates(false);
            updateHandler.postDelayed(periodicUpdate, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        } else {
            updateHandler.removeCallbacks(periodicUpdate);  // no network anyway
        }
    }
};

private void setupVariables(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;

    packageName = context.getPackageName();
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences( packageName + "_" + TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    device_id = crc32(Secure.getString( context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID));
    last_update = preferences.getLong("last_update", 0);
    NOTIFICATION_ID += crc32(packageName);
 //     schedule.add(new ScheduleEntry(0,24));

    ApplicationInfo appinfo = context.getApplicationInfo();
    if( appinfo.icon != 0 ) {
        appIcon = appinfo.icon;
    } else {
        Log_w(TAG, "unable to find application icon");
    }
    if( appinfo.labelRes != 0 ) {
        appName = context.getString(appinfo.labelRes);
    } else {
        Log_w(TAG, "unable to find application label");
    }
    if( new File(appinfo.sourceDir).lastModified() > preferences.getLong(MD5_TIME, 0) ) {
        preferences.edit().putString( MD5_KEY, MD5Hex(appinfo.sourceDir)).commit();
        preferences.edit().putLong( MD5_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();

        String update_file = preferences.getString(UPDATE_FILE, "");
        if( update_file.length() > 0 ) {
            if( new File( context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + update_file ).delete() ) {
                preferences.edit().remove(UPDATE_FILE).remove(SILENT_FAILED).commit();
            }
        }
    }
    raise_notification();

    if( haveInternetPermissions() ) {
        context.registerReceiver( connectivity_receiver,
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
}

private boolean checkSchedule() {
    if( schedule.size() == 0 ) return true; // empty schedule always fits

    int now = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    for( ScheduleEntry e : schedule ) {
        if( now >= e.start && now < e.end ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// required in order to prevent issues in earlier Android version.
private static void disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary() {
    // see HttpURLConnection API doc
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    }
}
 private static ArrayList<ScheduleEntry> schedule = new   ArrayList<ScheduleEntry>();

private Runnable periodicUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        checkUpdates(false);
        updateHandler.removeCallbacks(periodicUpdate);  // remove whatever others may have posted
        updateHandler.postDelayed(this, WAKEUP_INTERVAL);
    }
};

private BroadcastReceiver connectivity_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        // do application-specific task(s) based on the current network state, such
        // as enabling queuing of HTTP requests when currentNetworkInfo is connected etc.
        boolean not_mobile = currentNetworkInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE") ? false : true;
        if( currentNetworkInfo.isConnected() && (mobile_updates || not_mobile) ) {
            checkUpdates(false);
            updateHandler.postDelayed(periodicUpdate, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        } else {
            updateHandler.removeCallbacks(periodicUpdate);  // no network anyway
        }
    }
};

private void setupVariables(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;

    packageName = context.getPackageName();
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences( packageName + "_" + TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    device_id = crc32(Secure.getString( context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID));
    last_update = preferences.getLong("last_update", 0);
    NOTIFICATION_ID += crc32(packageName);
 //     schedule.add(new ScheduleEntry(0,24));

    ApplicationInfo appinfo = context.getApplicationInfo();
    if( appinfo.icon != 0 ) {
        appIcon = appinfo.icon;
    } else {
        Log_w(TAG, "unable to find application icon");
    }
    if( appinfo.labelRes != 0 ) {
        appName = context.getString(appinfo.labelRes);
    } else {
        Log_w(TAG, "unable to find application label");
    }
    if( new File(appinfo.sourceDir).lastModified() > preferences.getLong(MD5_TIME, 0) ) {
        preferences.edit().putString( MD5_KEY, MD5Hex(appinfo.sourceDir)).commit();
        preferences.edit().putLong( MD5_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();

        String update_file = preferences.getString(UPDATE_FILE, "");
        if( update_file.length() > 0 ) {
            if( new File( context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + update_file ).delete() ) {
                preferences.edit().remove(UPDATE_FILE).remove(SILENT_FAILED).commit();
            }
        }
    }
    raise_notification();

    if( haveInternetPermissions() ) {
        context.registerReceiver( connectivity_receiver,
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
}

private boolean checkSchedule() {
    if( schedule.size() == 0 ) return true; // empty schedule always fits

    int now = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    for( ScheduleEntry e : schedule ) {
        if( now >= e.start && now < e.end ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// required in order to prevent issues in earlier Android version.
private static void disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary() {
    // see HttpURLConnection API doc
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does GitHub have a limit on access?

Comment: not github exactly its the website it uses to check for an update only allows 2gb of download data a month.. i have over 4000 members with our app.. and all the data allowace was used in the first week.. i know its open source so there has t be an alternative option.

Comment: I know what Dropbox is :) I'm saying that if your app is open source, then it should be on Github or similar site, where there is a Releases platform. I was asking if you have considered that as an alternative to Dropbox

Comment: its not drop box that the issue it auto updateapk which is open source but charge a small fortune to actually make it work correctly.
http://auto-update-apk.appspot.com/

Comment: Oh, I see. Umm, well your manifest contains the version code / number of the app. So, if you can get access to a text file, or just a REST API endpoint to tell you the latest number, then you just need to do a simple string comparison, right?

Comment: yeah thats what i need

Comment: I don't see where you are using the `API_URL`, so how are you communicating with the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120806/discussion-between-mark-harrop-and-cricket-007).